# Dimensional Date Table with multiple first day of weeks

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

I am about to start creating a dimensional date table for a Data Warehouse project using SQl Server 2012.

On of the first user comments is that....

'Different customers will have a different first day of week, so not always a Monday'.

How would I accomodate for potentially 7 different start of week days in a single dim table or should i simply calculate it the conventional way on the fly on a per customer basis in a fact table and not use the dim date table?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1. Calculate it on the fly using built in date match functions.  SQL Server defaults to Sunday as the first day of the week.

Option 2. Create an additional column in your table for each day of the week indicating its day number of the week.  For example column TuesdayFirst would have a 1 for every Tuesday and a 2 for each Wednesday.

Option 3. (Best) Create a view on your date dimension that calculates the additional columns for each day.  Any of the columns that are not needed in the select will be ignored and not calculated.  This gives the benefits of the persistent columns and the consistent calculation method, but does have some processing overhead versus pre-calculating.

If you choose option 3, do not use a CASE statement to calculate it.  You must do it strictly with date math in order for it to perform decently when aggregating.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wes.
I like the idea of option 3.  So just to get this right...

The view would include all possible start days or just the one on a 'on demand basis'?
What about all the attributes on th eoriginal Dim date table that will be affected by this different start day?  i.e. if 'Wednesday' then [StartOfWeekDate] =Wednesay date, [EndOfWeekDate]= Tuesday date, [DayofWeek] and possibly [DayNumber]. Is Wednesday now '1' or the stays as the default '2'?
Granted, there will only be a few affected attributes so not sure if the view will contain all the above attributes x 7?

Comment: If you'll need all of the week based columns for each customer, yes you would need to have seven for each attribute.  If you do this and you're using SSAS, I highly recommend you use folders in your cube date dimension to better organize it for your end users.  If Wednesday if the first day of the week, I would expect it to be day 1 of the week.